# encoding error with russian website

Tags: php, image, character, cyrillic

I have russian website that stores data in MYSQL database. I have russian characters correct on my database and they are all fine on my page as well, I mean when I view source of my page everything is OK, but images with name that contains russian characters are not displayed on my page, but link to image is correct:
background-image:url(../../images/content_image/ОНас_menu.png);

but when I press this link this error comes:
The requested URL "/images/content_image/%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81_menu.png" was not found on this server.

Comment: This can also be a sign that your webserver is misconfigured for your file-systems encoding. Just noting, it's like what @ObmerkKronen wrote, you are way to unspecific to make a good suggestion where the encoding chain gets broken. Please improve your question and provide more facts.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

are your answers ..

and since you have posted no code , it will be hard to establish where exactly you will need to implement them.